# Push notifications not working after generating new certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

My app was configured to use push notifications and was working fine. My certificate expired and another of the team members created a new cert and sent me the p12 file to use. Got the certificate and updated the mobileprovision to use this new certificate.

I also regenerated the pem files for push notification. But now my push notifications don't work.

I tried generating the pem files twice already but apns wouldn't work.

Can someone let me know what the issue could be?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you NSLog the error on this function ? - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error;

Comment: Yes tried already, the log is not printed and I get a device token as well.

Comment: I had a problem like this before. I had to recreate the provisioning. I'm not sure if this will work for you.

Comment: Tried doing that as well. Regenerated the pem, mobileprovision. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, that is all I have. If you don't get any errors from the device when registering, it seem the provisioning is ok. May be there is something wrong about the creation of the pem file. Or may be your server script is not pointing to the right certificate.

Comment: Could anyone please help in resolving this issue. Even I am stuck badly here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Perform a soft-reset of the device
2. Turned off push notifications on the device and turned them on again
3. Turned off push notifications for the app and turned them on again in the settings

Not sure what part made the difference but push notifications work again!! Yay!!

Answer (score 1):

Take in mind that if there is an invalid deviceToken sent when sending notifications, Apple will silently drop every message sent.
So I guess that the problem may be that you have invalid deviceToken (probably from previous cert) that are being sent with your current cert.
Are you registering with the Feedback service?

Comment: The devicetoken is correct - checked. I also did a check on feedback services. that doesn't return an error either.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure whether Push Notification option is enabled while regenerating the certificate. If it worked with the previous certificate and stopped working after re-generating the new certificate it may be the cause.

Validate whether the Push Notification option is enabled in the identifier which is used as part of the regeneration of the new certificate.