# Azure service refering old certificate

Tags: c#, ios, windows, azure, apple-push-notifications

My iOS application is a year old and it was working fine with push notification. but we have changed push certificate on azure because developer's account has expired.
From then we are getting error like

'Received certificate has expired'

But my certificate are upto date, its working fine when using from local machine. Also certificates are sending push to iOS APP by 'Pushmebabby' APNs test app.

Please help me to resolve this issue. I am stuck on this issue since last 2 days and still could not able to find any solution.

Sunil

Comment: have you checked this SO question before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262246/push-notifications-not-working-after-generating-new-certificate?rq=1

Comment: @astaykon Problem is not from device side. I am receiving notification when trying with local certificate with azure service but when putting that on live its not working.